# How a Proof Assistant Proves ∀ or ∃

Tags: math

Wondering how a proof assistant such as Coq proves **forall** or **exists**. For [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation):

[image]

Three aspects:

1. If you were to give it a huge set of items like a million, wondering if it would actually iterate through it 3x and compare all the values to prove the transitive relation holds.
2. If not, then wondering if it doesn't even need such an "example" group, and instead it can just work on the definition itself, and how that would work.
3. Or is this proof definition defining a set *in advance*, so it provably has the transitive relation from the start. If so, how that works.

Say you want to prove some set has the transitive property, wondering how the proof assistant goes about proving that, how it works under the hood.

Comment: I think you're in the wrong place.  Did you mean to post this on https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I posted it there but they voted to close it as off topic lol. It is sort of about programming since it's the implementation of the assistant.

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to have much to do with Software Engineering. We're not really in the business of dissecting or reverse-engineering corporate software.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: it is a question about an algorithm, which makes it IMHO on topic here - at least, formally. However, not sure if our community has many experts for this very specific kind of algorithmic domain.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more concrete examples of how this is used.  Are you talking generic sets of data or sets with a mathematical definition?  It's not clear what the scope is here.

Comment: Both, I'm not really sure how it should be defined. One aspect (1) is, given a set of data how to prove it. The other (2) is if you're _defining_ a set of data, like creating a type or something, then how to prove that forall of that type (i.e. instances) it satisfies the property (it seems then that any instance of the type you'd create would then have to satisfy that property), so yeah probably (2) is better to know about. The first one seems like you'd _have_ to iterate through it.

Comment: I agree it is an algorithm question, and probably one of the more common ones about this type of tool.

Comment: It'd help people understand programming in Coq. @LancePollard about the question itself, I thought Coq can't prove such theorem, you need to supply the steps to prove that theorem and Coq evaluate those steps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, #2. The language takes the declared initial states and uses Boolean logic transitions to make sure that there are no contradictions in the interactions between all of the rules defined. Pretty much like any philosophy or math major would do when proving logical assertions, but in an automated (and less error prone) manner.